# Calling non-strict function in Scala with explicit types doesn't compile, inferred types works

Tags: scala, types, lazy-evaluation, type-inference

Working through the excellent "FP in Scala" by Chiusano Rúnar Bjarnason, had a strange compilation error when trying to implement Stream#takeWhile lazily through #foldRight. Given the following code in the book (also on [GitHub](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala)):

```scala
trait Stream[+A] {
  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = 
    this match {
      case Cons(h,t) => f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f))
      case _ => z
}

case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty
}
```

I tried:

```scala
def takeWhile_fold(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
  foldRight(empty[A])((it:A, acc:Stream[A]) => if (p(it)) cons(it, acc) else acc)
```

But this gives the compilation fault:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (A, fpinscala.laziness.Stream[A]) => fpinscala.laziness.Stream[A]
[error]  required: (A, => fpinscala.laziness.Stream[A]) => fpinscala.laziness.Stream[A]
[error]       foldRight(empty[A])((it:A, acc:Stream[A]) => if (p(it)) cons(it, acc) else ac
```

But if I remove the types on the lambda, it works:

```scala
def takeWhile_fold(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
  foldRight(empty[A])((it, acc) => if (p(it)) cons(it, acc) else acc)
```

There is no way in Scala to state in the calling code that it should be a by-name parameter, is there? (Does it even make sense for the caller, it is the receiver that decides, right?) Attempting:

```scala
def takeWhile_fold(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
  foldRight(empty[A])((it, acc: => Stream[A]) => if (p(it)) cons(it, acc) else acc)
```

Gives another compilation error:

```scala
[error]      identifier expected but '=>' found.
[error]       foldRight(empty[A])((it, acc: => Stream[A]) => if (p(it)) cons(it, acc) else acc)
                                            ^
[error]  ')' expected but '}' found.
[error] }
[error] ^
[error] two errors found
```

I've solved the exercise, but my questions are - why doesn't it work with explicit types? Do they enforce strictness somehow while the receiver must have non-strict? And if so, is there any syntax in Scala so the caller can signal that "yes, this is by-name parameters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by-name ends up being part of the signature. You can imagine that by-name parameters are implemented by the compiler by translating this:

```
def foo(n: => Int) = ... n ...
```

to this:

```
def foo(n: () => Int) = ... n() ...
```

A side effect of this is that, if you reference by-name parameters multiple times, they will be evaluated multiple times. So this:

```
def bar(n: => Int) = n + n
bar( { println("foo"); 5 } )
```

Will print foo twice before returning 10. It's the same as this:

```
def bar(n: () => Int) = n() + n()
bar { () => println("foo"); 5 }
```

As for whether you can explicitly state that a lambda takes by-name parameters... I'm not sure. I tried this:

```
def foo( f: ( => Int) => Int ) = f({ println("foo"); 5 })
foo { (a) => a + a }
```

Which worked. I tried these:

```
foo { (a : Int ) => a + a }
foo { (a : => Int ) => a + a }
```

Which failed.

The spec seems to [indicate](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#function-declarations-and-definitions) that the type property of formal parameters to functions are generated with the `ParamType` syntax rule, whereas the type property of [anonymous functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions) parameters uses the plain `Type` rule. And the `=>` by-name indicator is on `ParamType`.